# Chrome tab or bookmark scrolling affects angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

Weird issue I've encountered, I have a angularjs page that features a slick carrousel, and in the controller I listen for the $destroy event in order to remove the injected elements by slick. For some reason, whenever I scroll over my Chrome bookmarks or tabs, the carrousel gets clipped, which also happens during the controller's destroy event.
Are they related at all, or just a coincidence? If related, is this related to chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, was related to a rendering issue that Chrome has with fixed top elements. Including a -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) on it fixed it.